# python game to check index postion

Tags: python

This game checks the user input and list position. if they match, it's correct else wrong. It seems like my program is having issues with variable scope. Can someone guide me here?`

```
from random import shuffle

def game():
    my_list=['','O','']
    shuffle(my_list)
    guess=None
    choice=None
    
    def option_select():
        
        while guess not in [0,1,2]:
            guess= int(input("Select the position: 0 or 1 or 2"))
        return 
    
    def check_answer():
        if my_list[guess]=='O':
            print("Correct choice")
            print(my_list)
        else:
            print("Wrong choice")
            print(my_list)
            
    def play_again():
        print("Play again?")
        while choice not in [0,1]:
            choice= int(input("Press 0 to play again, 1 to quit"))
        
        if choice==0:
            game()
        else:
            return
```

I tried to change location of variable and also tried using global keyword with variables. nothing works

Comment: you can have a function with functions inside, but it would make more sense to make game a class instead of a function.

Comment: Hallo Anurag,

There's some code missing, because there's no part where you execute the game() function, can you upload the rest of the code?

Second, I see a conditional where you're saying choice == 0, if you're getting input from a user it should come in str type, We don't know if you're converting that

Comment: @Elerium115 I am still learning. using class is still a little ahead in the course. Thanks still, class might make it more simple and easy to execute.

Comment: @vgenovpy There is no rest of the code :) , the program will run as soon as i place game(). I have converted choice input datatype to int in the play_again function.

Comment: Sorry guys. just learned that functions inside function don't run automatically if i call the game() function here, it wont run the other nested functions, i would have to explicitly call them, either inside the game function or outside anywhere maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify program by merging all functions:

```
from random import shuffle

LIST = ['', '0', '']

while True:
    shuffle(LIST)
    guess = int(input('Select the position: 0 or 1 or 2: '))
    if LIST[guess] == '0':
        print('Correct choice')
    else:
        print('Wrong choice')

    choice = input('Press 0 to play again, 1 to quit: ')
    if choice == '0':
        continue
    if choice == '1':
        break
```

Output:

```
Select the position: 0 or 1 or 2: 0
Wrong choice
Press 0 to play again, 1 to quit: 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is more simple and easy to implement.